# Chain requests and return both results with RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, chaining

I have a `ContentService` that makes a request for an article. That article response contains an `authorId` property.

I have a `ProfileService` that allows me to request a user profile by an `userId`.

I am trying to request an article from the `ContentService`, chain on a request once that completes to the `ProfileService` using the `authorId` property, I would then like to return a `ContentArticleViewModel` that contains both the article and profile information.

My `ArticleInteractor` looks something like this -

```swift
final class ArticleInteractor: ArticleInteractorInputProtocol {

    let fetchArticleTrigger = PublishSubject<String>()

    private lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    weak var output: ArticleInteractorOutputProtocol? {
        didSet {
            configureSubscriptions()
        }
    }

    private func configureSubscriptions() {
        guard let output = output else { return }

        fetchArticleTrigger
            .bind(to: dependencies.contentSvc.fetchContentByIdTrigger)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        dependencies.contentSvc.fetchContentByIdResponse
            .bind(to: output.fetchArticleResponse)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Quite simply `fetchArticleTrigger` starts a request, I then `bind` on `dependencies.contentSvc.fetchContentByIdResponse` and pick up the response.

The method on my `ContentService` is -

```swift
    // MARK:- FetchContentById
    // @params: id - String
    // return: PublishSubject<ContentArticle>

        fetchContentByIdTrigger
            .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] in self.client.request(.getContentById(id: $0)) }
            .map { (resp: Result<ContentArticle>) in
                guard case .success(let props) = resp else { return ContentArticle() }
                return props
        }
        .bind(to: fetchContentByIdResponse)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I have a very similair setup on my `ProfileService` -

```swift
    // MARK:- FetchUserProfileById
    // @params: id - String
    // return: PublishSubject<User>
        fetchUserProfileByIdTrigger
            .flatMapLatest { [unowned self] in self.client.request(.getProfileByUserId(id: $0)) }
            .map { (resp: Result<User>) in
                guard case .success(let props) = resp else { return User() }
                return props
        }
        .bind(to: fetchUserProfileByIdResponse)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I imagine I will create a model for the article, something like -

```swift
struct ContentArticleViewModel {
    var post: ContentArticle
    var user: User
}
```

I was imaging something like this pseudo code within my `ArticleInteractor`-

```swift
    dependencies.contentSvc.fetchContentByIdResponse
        .flatMapLatest { article in
             /* fetch profile using `article.authorId */
        }.map { article, profile in
            return ContentArticleViewModel(post: article, user: profile)
        }
        .bind(to: output.fetchArticleResponse)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But I am completely lost how best to handle this. I have seen a number of articles on chaining requests but am struggling to apply anything successfully.

**EDIT**

I have something working currently -

```swift
    private func configureSubscriptions() {
        guard let output = output else { return }

        fetchArticleTrigger
            .bind(to: dependencies.contentSvc.fetchContentByIdTrigger)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        dependencies.contentSvc.fetchContentByIdResponse
            .do(onNext: { [unowned self] article in self.dependencies.profileSvc.fetchUserProfileByIdTrigger.onNext(article.creator.userId)})
            .bind(to: fetchArticleResponse)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        let resp = Observable.combineLatest(fetchArticleResponse, dependencies.profileSvc.fetchUserProfileByIdResponse)

        resp
            .map { [unowned self] in self.enrichArticleAuthorProps(article: $0, user: $1) }
            .bind(to: output.fetchArticleResponse)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func enrichArticleAuthorProps(article: ContentArticle, user: User) -> ContentArticle {
        var updatedArticle = article
        updatedArticle.creator = user
        return updatedArticle
    }
```

I am not sure this is correct however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have so much code for such a small job. Below is an example that does what you describe (downloads the article, the downloads the author profile and emits both) with far less code and even *it* is more code than I would normally use.

```
protocol ContentService {
    func requestArticle(id: String) -> Observable<Article>
    func requestProfile(id: String) -> Observable<User>
}

class Example {
    let service: ContentService
    init(service: ContentService) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func bind(trigger: Observable<String>) -> Observable<(Article, User)> {
        let service = self.service
        return trigger
            .flatMapLatest { service.requestArticle(id: $0) }
            .flatMapLatest {
                Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just($0), service.requestProfile(id: $0.authorId))
            }
    }
}
```

Or maybe you want to display the article while waiting for the author profile to download. In that case something like this:

```
func bind(trigger: Observable<String>) -> (article: Observable<Article>, author: Observable<User>) {
    let service = self.service
    let article = trigger
        .flatMapLatest { service.requestArticle(id: $0) }
        .share(replay: 1)

    let author = article
        .flatMapLatest {
            service.requestProfile(id: $0.authorId)
    }

    return (article, author)
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I was seriously over complicating things - I see that now, thank you Daniel, that has helped point me in a much clearer direction